# Add custom context menu to explorer for directory\background

Tags: registry

I have successfully added my own context menu item to all files (`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\[mycontextmenu]`) as well as to folders (`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\\[mycontextmenu]`), but when I add it to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\\[mycontextmenu]`, it throws the error

> This file does not have a program associated with it for performing this action. Please install a program or, if one is already installed, create an association in the Default Programs control panel.".`

Everything I've googled says to just associate a file to a specific application, I just want to execute MY application, and pass the directory that the user right-clicked in.

Any help, or links to where I can find out how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Here's](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/add-any-application-to-the-desktop-right-click-menu-in-vista/) the link that shows how to do this, and the %V is the parameter to get the path where it was clicked from.

Comment: Thank you! I was scratching my head why %1 did not work for 'Directory\Background\shell' but it did for 'Folder\shell'